# How to get error message from response body using jsonPath

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am testing my API which I've created using Java and Spring Boot.
I have a test method which returns me a 404 not found (which is intended) and I need to access the error message that is returned. Here's the response:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2022-08-30T13:20:22.062+00:00",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "Name does not exist",
    "path": "/mutualFundNav/sds"
}
```

I need to get the "message" variable and ensure the correct error message is displayed. I tried the following code:

```
    @Test
    void whenNonExistingNamePassedInThenReturn404() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get(BASE_URL + END_POINT + "/Non existent name")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().is4xxClientError())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.message", Matchers.is(NAME_NOT_FOUND)));
    }
```

When I run this method, I do indeed get a 404 not found error like intended, but I'm unable to retrieve the error message. I get an error like this:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: No value at JSON path "$.message"
```

Comment: you can see the response body in console, can you please added it to question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@Test
void whenNonExistingNamePassedInThenReturn404() throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform(get(BASE_URL + END_POINT + "/Non existent name")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(status().is4xxClientError())
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$['message']", Matchers.is(NAME_NOT_FOUND)));
}
```